Issue with run-android command
When I run command npx react-native run-android I get this error:

**
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'AwesomeProject'.

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'.
Service 'SystemInfo' is not available (os=Windows 11 10.0 amd64, enabled=false).
**

I tried to clear gradle cache but that didn't solve the issue.

I think you are facing an issue in the React Native Environment.
Run this command npx react-native doctor in the terminal.

This issue was resolved when I deleted the repository and reinstalled React Native, but another issue has now occurred.

"A new issue has occurred: java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\Sreya\Desktop\sreya\love-knot\android.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-a4bfdb9a-3a8e-40d1-895b-328f0f4c6181) to immutable location (C:\Users\Sreya\Desktop\sreya\love-knot\android.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a)."

Try to change the gradle version. your version is 8.6. Lower it to 8.5.
change gradle wrapper properties :
[YourAppName]/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties : distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-all.zip

Also, run the command npx react-native doctor in terminal to ensure your environment is setup correctly.
